Evidence for the king and his Sefer Torah
One of the most defining characteristics of the Torah's king (Parshas Shoftim) is that he writes himself a Sefer Torah, carries it at all times, is constantly reading it "all the days of his life", constantly re-orienting himself to represent Hashem and his Torah.
My son asked me, Do we have any indication in Nach that one of the kings, even a good one, did any of that?

"מה אהבתי תורתך, כל היום היא שיחתי"? (David, Tehillim 119:97)

See Sanhedrin 102b - the מחמד עיניים of Achav (Melachim 1:20:6) is understood to be his sefer torah.

Do we have any indication of Nachic kings observing Biblical Mitzvos? No. Do we have any archeological or paleographic evidence of ancient Judeans being aware of the Torah commandments? According to https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6q80lDYQwtE, no.

Do we have scriptural evidence for widespread observation of [other] Biblical Mitzvos in the Iron Age? No. Do we have archeological or paleographic evidence for that? Also no. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6q80lDYQwtE

To people who may read the comments section, I wouldn't put too much weight on Yonatan Adler's views. He's a good archeologist, and yes, he comes from a dati background, but when he gets down to the historical explanations of his findings, he's the sort of person who shoots the arrow and draws the target. Don't let the kippa fool you. Cf. for example the almost complete lack of non-kosher animal bones in Israelite sites.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

@JoelK Who says it was his personal Sefer Torah?

@MichoelR See Malbim to the pasuk in Melachim

This is a weird question. It is like asking, "Is there any evidence that a tzaddik ate kosher?" Well, it he's a tzaddik, then he obviously ate kosher. If the passuk says someone was righteous, they obviously fulfilled the commandments that applied to them, including a king writing a sefer Torah.

@N.T. To me it seems reasonable. Obviously we can't demand that for every one of the Taryag Mitzvos, we find evidence in Tanach that they were done. But the Torah stresses this so. Rambam: "should not move from his presence...
When he goes to war, this scroll accompanies him. When he returns... When he sits in judgement.... When he dines, it should be opposite him...
" I have an impression that anyone dealing with the king is going to deal with his Sefer Torah, which he is always carrying around, and reading anytime he isn't doing something else. So my son was wondering if you see that.
